# How to use <object> in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I feel like I'm having a brain freeze, but I can't get an object tag browser plugin to work with Meteor. Meteor throws an error in the Firefox console "id must be a string". And when viewing the ui.js code it looks like meteor code is trying to append to the DOM but cannot. This looks simple as the  tag is a basic component of browser plug-ins/extensions. Am I missing something?

```
<object id="testPdf" data="lorem.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>

Error: id must be a string       ui.js:856
```

Comment: Considering that Meteor compiles your html templates into ASTs, it might as well be a bug in parser. Opening a ticket on github might be a good idea.

Comment: linking for the future reference: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2119

Comment: Give us more. How you inject it in template for instance.